# ttyUSB not showing for GSM modem in Ubuntu 20..04

Tags: drivers, usb, usb-modem, modem

I am using a GSM modem to try to send SMS, the modem model is from TCT Mobile X230L on Ubuntu

```
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

, the modem is recognized and can see it under `lsusb` and here is the output:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 1bbb:f000 T & A Mobile Phones
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

the device is the second one :`ID 1bbb:f000`

I tried to use the log and disconnect and connect the modem and I got this:

```
Nov  3 16:36:38 OPC kernel: [ 1180.292531] usb 2-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=a4a5,
Nov  3 18:01:24 OPC kernel: [ 3006.970800] usb 2-1.4: new high-speed USB device                                                                              number 9 using ehci-pci

Nov  3 18:01:24 OPC kernel: [ 3007.081976] usb 2-1.4: New USB device found, idVe                                                                             ndor=1bbb, idProduct=f000, bcdDevice= 0.00
Nov  3 18:01:24 OPC kernel: [ 3007.081980] usb 2-1.4: New USB device strings: Mf                                                                             r=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
Nov  3 18:01:24 OPC kernel: [ 3007.081983] usb 2-1.4: Product: HSPA Data Card
Nov  3 18:01:24 OPC kernel: [ 3007.081984] usb 2-1.4: Manufacturer: USBModem
Nov  3 18:01:24 OPC kernel: [ 3007.081986] usb 2-1.4: SerialNumber: 1234567890AB                                                                             CDEF
Nov  3 18:01:24 OPC kernel: [ 3007.084822] usb-storage 2-1.4:1.0: USB Mass Stora                                                                             ge device detected
Nov  3 18:01:24 OPC kernel: [ 3007.084972] scsi host6: usb-storage 2-1.4:1.0
Nov  3 18:01:24 OPC mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 9: "/sys/devices/pci0000:0                                                                             0/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4"
Nov  3 18:01:24 OPC mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 9 was not an MTP device
Nov  3 18:01:25 OPC systemd[1]: Starting USB_ModeSwitch_2-1.4...
Nov  3 18:01:25 OPC usb_modeswitch_dispatcher[5843]: Could not read attribute: N                                                                             o such file or directory
Nov  3 18:01:25 OPC usb_modeswitch_dispatcher[5843]: message repeated 2 times: [                                                                              Could not read attribute: No such file or directory]
Nov  3 18:01:25 OPC systemd[1]: usb_modeswitch@2-1.4.service: Main process exite                                                                             d, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov  3 18:01:25 OPC systemd[1]: usb_modeswitch@2-1.4.service: Failed with result                                                                              'exit-code'.
Nov  3 18:01:25 OPC systemd[1]: Failed to start USB_ModeSwitch_2-1.4.
Nov  3 18:01:25 OPC mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 9: "/sys/devices/pci0000:0                                                                             0/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4"
Nov  3 18:01:25 OPC mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 9 was not an MTP device

Nov  3 18:01:25 OPC kernel: [ 3008.089497] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ALCAT                                                                             EL  Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Nov  3 18:01:25 OPC kernel: [ 3008.090481] scsi 6:0:0:1: CD-ROM            ALCAT                                                                             EL  Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Nov  3 18:01:25 OPC kernel: [ 3008.090890] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1                                                                              type 0
Nov  3 18:01:25 OPC kernel: [ 3008.094473] sr 6:0:0:1: [sr0] scsi-1 drive
Nov  3 18:01:26 OPC kernel: [ 3008.111101] sr 6:0:0:1: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
Nov  3 18:01:26 OPC kernel: [ 3008.111260] sr 6:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2                                                                              type 5
Nov  3 18:01:26 OPC kernel: [ 3008.112084] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI remov                                                                             able disk
Nov  3 18:01:26 OPC kernel: [ 3008.323650] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet                                                                              Level 1
Nov  3 18:01:26 OPC kernel: [ 3008.323673] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
Nov  3 18:01:26 OPC systemd[1]: Finished Clean the /media/root/Quick net mount p                                                                             oint.
Nov  3 18:01:26 OPC udisksd[688]: Mounted /dev/sr0 at /media/root/Quick net on b                                                                             ehalf of uid 0
Nov  3 18:01:56 OPC tracker-store[5821]: OK
Nov  3 18:01:56 OPC systemd[1410]: tracker-store.service: Succeeded.
```

the output of `dmesg` :

```
[ 3007.084972] scsi host6: usb-storage 2-1.4:1.0
[ 3008.089497] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ALCATEL  Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 3008.090481] scsi 6:0:0:1: CD-ROM            ALCATEL  Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 3008.090890] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 3008.094473] sr 6:0:0:1: [sr0] scsi-1 drive
[ 3008.111101] sr 6:0:0:1: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[ 3008.111260] sr 6:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[ 3008.112084] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 3008.323650] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 1
[ 3008.323673] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
```

and here is the output of usb_modeswitch:

```
Look for target devices ...
 Found devices in target mode or class (1)
Look for default devices ...
 Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 009 on bus 002
Get the current device configuration ...
Current configuration number is 1
Use interface number 0
 with class 8
Use endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x81 (in)
Looking for active drivers ...
 OK, driver detached
Set up interface 0
Use endpoint 0x01 for message sending ...
Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x01 ...
 OK, message successfully sent
Read the response to message 1 (CSW) ...
 Response successfully read (13 bytes), status 1
Reset response endpoint 0x81
Reset message endpoint 0x01
-> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye!
```

but couldn't see the `ttyUSB` and here is the output:

```
[    0.077109] printk: console [tty0] enabled
```

what could be the issue here?

sorry for all of those logs just I tried all things but couldn't find the solution!

Comment: Any Idea, please

Comment: please show `id` and `loginctl` why is the virtual disk from your modem mounted under `/media/root`

Comment: @nobody the output of loginctl: `root@OPC:/home/opc# loginctl
SESSION  UID USER SEAT  TTY
      2 1000 opc        pts/0
     c1  125 gdm  seat0 tty1

2 sessions listed.
root@OPC:/home/opc#
`

Comment: @nobody output of id: `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`

Comment: why are you logged in as root. `lsb_release -rd`